# Mileage calc using code/script doesn't look 4 cells just 2. Needhelp

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Im calculating mileage in google sheet and I have the below code which works perfectly but it's reading only 2 cells. I would need the code to read 4 cells if that is something possible.
I'm new to code writing so not much experience yet.

It needs to read 4 cells because we have set places where the driver goes so I have them in a dropped down in the form but sometimes they go to new places so they have the option to add those themselves. But the below code won't pick those up.

```
function DrivingMeters(origin, destination) { 
   var directions = Maps.newDirectionFinder()
  .setOrigin(origin)
  .setDestination(destination)
  .getDirections();
  Utilities.sleep(100000);
  return directions.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value;
}

function DrivingMiles(origin, destination) {
  return DrivingMeters(origin, destination)/1609.34;
  Utilities.sleep(100000);
}

function DrivingSeconds(origin, destination) 
  var directions = Maps.newDirectionFinder()
  .setOrigin(origin)
  .setDestination(destination)
  .getDirections();
  return directions.routes[0].legs[0].duration.value;
  Utilities.sleep(100000);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `addWaypoint`. Code below shows how to get the total distance. `calculateDistance` below accepts at least 2 locations. Adjust accordingly in getting miles and duration.

#### Code:

```
function calculateDistance(...locations){
  // accepts any number of locations but should at least be 2
  if(locations.length < 2) {
    return "Needs at least 2 locations";
  }

  // remove 1st location before looping and set it as origin
  var directions = Maps.newDirectionFinder().setOrigin(locations.shift());
  
  while(locations.length > 0) {
    // every non-final location is treated as waypoint
    if(locations.length > 1) 
      directions = directions.addWaypoint(locations.shift());
    // last location is always treated as destination
    else
      directions = directions.setDestination(locations.shift())
                             .setMode(Maps.DirectionFinder.Mode.DRIVING)
                             .getDirections();
  }

  var total_distance = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < directions.routes[0].legs.length; i++)
    total_distance += directions.routes[0].legs[i].distance.value;

  return total_distance;
}
```

#### Output:

[image: output]

#### EDIT:

- Since you can have blank cells, to make it easy, `filter` and use only parameters with values.

#### Sample:

[image: sample data]

#### Code modification:

```
function calculateDistance(...locations){
  // filter data to remove blank cells
  locations = locations.filter(Boolean);

  // accepts any number of locations, except 1
  if(locations.length < 2) {
    return "Needs at least 2 locations";
  }
```

#### Note:

- Just pass ALL 4 cells from `C` to `F` one by one. (e.g. `=calculateDistance(C2,D2,E2,F2)`)

#### Reference:

- [addWayPoint](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/maps/direction-finder#addwaypointaddress)
- [Spread syntax (...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)
- [Array.prototype.shift()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift)
- [filter](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_filter.asp)

Comment: I just tried it and my problem is that I use columns from C to F and the places always just in two cells. So maybe 1 postcode in C (as that not on the form so its new place) but from there he went to something thats on the list and that would go to F. So C-D are if they add postcode and E-F is something that is on the form. How could I make it work that it looks these 4 cells and calculate distance in the two that is in any of these two cells?

Comment: @user15122538, kindly share or at least show how the sheet looks on your post so we can have a clear look at it.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AeMCudElBBPaMIFMk3FoSpanG_glc3hVvEU0_3LrSZE/edit?usp=sharing, Here is the link to a copy i made. i just added random postcodes. I have left the first comment code in so I just wrote the mile in to show what Im thinking. No point to have the old code there as wasnt working the way I need it. if you need me to put it back let me know please

Comment: `setOrigin`, `setDestination` and `addWaypoint` all uses address or lat/long parameters. how do you intend on converting the said post codes to readable  parameters @user15122538?

Comment: Im absolutely new to coding so I have no clue. The original post one works with address and post code too.  I wished that could be amended to read 4 cells. I hope there is a way to make it work

Comment: I have updated the answer and below **"EDIT:"**, added a line containing `filter` to modify the code above. Make sure to pass `address` or `lat/long` instead of postal code @user15122538. The data returned is still in meters, just convert it if needed.

Comment: @user15122538, there is a built in function in sheets that converts `m` to `mi`. Final function will look something like this. `=convert(calculateDistance(C2,D2,E2,F2), "m", "mi") `